# How should I set up a new WordPress Theme without working on the live site?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to set up a new theme but don't want to make the changes live until it is completely configured. I came across a plugin called [Theme Test Drive](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-test-drive/). It states that it will allow you to test any theme but only the admin can see the changes. Does this mean I can use this plugin to work on a new theme then just make the theme live when I'm all done and the new site will be up and running? Also this is my first time changing themes. Do you lose all the content from the old theme when you change to the new (i.e. pictures and text). And if I reactivate the old theme will everything be back the way it was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a duplicate copy of your install into a testing environment either in a subdirectory or locally to test. The [Theme Test Drive](http://wordpress.org/plugins/sandbox/) plugin doesn't allow you to work with widgets or menus (from what I'm reading from the reviews.) Working on a testing environment is safer and offers more realistic test results. Try out the [Sandbox](http://wordpress.org/plugins/sandbox/) plugin, which works like this:

1. Sandbox copies your database tables into a new set of tables with a different prefix.
2. Data within the new database tables are updated to reflect the sandbox prefix.
3. Sandbox copies all files a new folder under the sandbox directory.
4. The plugin updates the configuration file within the sandbox to support the unique sandbox database prefix.

Once activated, only your browser can get to the sandbox installation keeping it secure and for your eyes only.

Hope this helps!